# Summarize behavior of $f(x)=x^n \sin\frac{1}{x}$ at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I need to describe the behavior of $f(x)=x^n \sin\frac{1}{x}$ at $x=0$. Define $f(0)=0$.

I have looked at $f(x)=x \sin\frac{1}{x}$, $f(x)=x^2 \sin\frac{1}{x}$, and $f(x)=x^3 \sin\frac{1}{x}$ and whether there is a limit at $x=0$ and if there is a derivative at $x=0$.

I know that $f(x)=x \sin\frac{1}{x}$ does have a limit at $x=0$ but is not differentiable at $x=0$; $f(x)=x^2 \sin\frac{1}{x}$ has a limit at $x=0$ but has no derivative at $x=0$; and $f(x)=x^3 \sin\frac{1}{x}$ has a limit at $x=0$ but no derivative at $x=0$.

Is there a pattern for the existence of the limit and derivative at $x=0$ as $n$ increases?

Comment: "I have looked at ..." Please do share what you found.

Comment: Actually, $f(x)=x \sin \frac 1x$ has a limit at $x=0$. Just apply the Sandwich Rule using the fact that $-1 \leq \sin \frac 1x \leq 1$.

Comment: If $f$ is not defined at zero then the derivative at zero cannot exists. The derivative of a function is defined (at most) on the domain of the original function.

Answer (score 0):

Well : $$\forall  \in \mathbb{R},  -1\le \sin(x)\le 1$$

By a change of variable this gives : $$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^*,  -1\le \sin({1\over x})\le 1$$

Now we can multiply each terms by $x^n$, giving : $$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^*,  -x^n\le f(x)\le x^n \Rightarrow \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^*, 0\le |f(x)|\le|x^n|$$

Assuming $n\ge1$ :$$\lim_{x\to 0} x^n = 0$$

We can conclude that $$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x) = 0$$

**NOTA BENE** : $f$ is not defined at $x=0$ but since it got a limit at $0$ we can 'expand' the domain of definition of $f$ to $x=0$ with $f(0)=0$

You can do a similar method for $f'(x)$ ( be carefull about the conditions on $n$ )